# Flume on edge or worker node?

Tags: hadoop, flume

For data ingestion, I would like to use flume and either put it on an edge node (in a secure DMZ outside the cluster) or on one of the worker nodes.

- Is there a best practice on where to put it?
- What are the advantages/disadvantages of each approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one problem with Flume on a worker node (ie a datanode). With HDFS, when you write data if the client is running on the datanode, the first replica of the data is always written to the local datanode.

So if you have many datanodes, and then you have Flume running on only a couple of them, those datanode will tend to have more space used than the other nodes. It really depends on how much data you plan to write with Flume on whether this may be a problem or not, and also whether you process the data after it is written too.

There could be good firewall / security reasons for having Flume on an edge node too - it really depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks! Haven't thought about the problem with writing data to the local data node